# How do I Loop Database Records in the View of C# MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone show me how to loop through my table in my view?
The rows I have are: `disease_id, disease, and remedy.`

## My DB Query

I tried to get all the results into a list, so i can loop through them in the view.

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM disease", m_DBCon);
        m_Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<string> record = new List<string>();
        while (m_Reader.Read())
        {
            string s = Convert.ToString(m_Reader[0]);
            record.Add(s);
        }

        ViewBag.Record = record;
```

## My View

I want to loop the database records in a table

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
    List<string> record = ViewBag.Record;
}
```

I keep getting an empty string. I thought I would have to do something like s["disease"], s["remedy"}, but s is a string so it doesn't have all those fields.

```
    @{
        foreach (string s in record)
        {
            <tr>
              <td>@s</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please give me some advice :)

Comment: jream - IMHO, you're doing this wrong on a number of levels 1. you should have an abstracted repository that you reference from your controller - you shouldn't EVER be dealing with SqlCommand in the controller action NEVER. Second, you don't define either a hard Model or better still, a ViewModel to capture the data required for the view. Not a cardinal sin but a real hinderance to maintainability and focus. My advice, look at doing all of this based on standard practice at a minimum and best practice as a goal. so sorry, you need to research mvc best practice ahead of this question

Comment: btw -apologies if the above sounds harsh, just want you to do things right, plus you'll find that dramatically, you're requirement for 'help' will diminish logarithmically to potential pleas for help. i know, coz i was you at one time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first want to point out that it's probably easier to create a DiseaseResult class first.
Such that :

```
public class DiseaseResult
{
  public int DiseaseId { get; set; }
  public string Disease { get; set; }
  public string Remedy { get; set; }
}
```

that makes things a little bit easier. Now you can say:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [disease_id], [disease], [remedy] FROM disease", m_DBCon);
    m_Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<DiseaseResult> record = new List<DiseaseResult>();
    while (m_Reader.Read())
    {
        record.Add(new DiseaseResult() { DiseaseId = m_Reader[0], Disease = m_Reader[1], Remedy = m_Reader[2]);
    }

    return View(record);
}
```

Afterward in your View:

```
@model List<DiseaseResult>

@foreach(DiseaseResult item in Model)
{
   <div>@item.Disease</div>
}
```

Comment: You can also make your life a lot easier by using a Entity Mapper or ORM framework like Dapper, EntityFramework, or Telerik OpenAccess. Even using a DataSet or DataTable.

Comment: I am a very big beginner I dont yet understand all this strict model casting stuff :(

Comment: +1 Mr young, you kinda encapsulte my comment in the OP question, tho i'd normally mark you down for perpetuating the SqlCommand access in the controller. go to work - refactor that into a GOOD answer using REPO pattern if you're up for it:) After all, using property getters/setters is SO much easier and bug free than  record[0]["disease_Id"] - yuck -disease ridden!

Comment: jim tollan, you are right. However; I got the vibe and JREAM comment confirmed he is a beginner. I wasn't trying to introduce much more complexity he might not understand. I left my example distilled for simplicity sake and beginner clarity sake.

Comment: Mr Young, completely understood  -therein tho lies the responsibility - be a good teacher... the rest will follow!

Comment: thanks you guys -- C# is much more difficult than a PHP MVC, lol! I believe the SQL queries should be in the Model itself (Or use Entity Framework) -- but Im so slow getting used to sending things back and forth and I just wanna finish something first :)

Answer (score 2):

The three items `disease_id`, `disease` and `remedy`, are they values or columns? How many records do you have in `desease` table? Seems that you are confusing "record" with collection of "fields values from different records". Try

```
string s = Convert.ToString(m_Reader[0]) + "," + Convert.ToString(m_Reader[1]) + "," + Convert.ToString(m_Reader[2]);
```

Comment: The three disease_id, disease, remedy are all column names. I only have 1 record in the table, but ill have about 20 :).

Comment: I guess I would want my items in an array, like: record[0]["disease_Id"], record[1]["disease_Id"], etc.. So I could loop through them and do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

My view code for the same environment is as such:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Item)
{ 
%>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%: item.Id %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%: item.Name %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<%
}
%>
```

Using a **var** instead of **string** allows the object your pulling from **record** to be cast implicitly rather than strongly.  I believe this is issue you're encountering in your code above.  Check out the following link for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think this the right way to go.  But, I don't think he is using the 'Model' object.  Rather he is using the ViewBag.Record.

Comment: Using `var` instead of a concrete type has nothing to do with the original problem. Even with `var`, the type of `item` must be deterministically derivable from the type of `Model.Item`.

Comment: Also, I would recommend using the @ symbol instead of <%.  To me it looks cleaner when using MVC3.

Comment: I see that now and think that Mr Young's answer is more acceptable.

Comment: I think somethings wrong with my initial loop that im casting stuff.

Comment: Yeah, disregard this and look at Mr Young's response.